# How to convert dataframe or matrix into a table

Tags: r

I have calculated mean, median, mode, SD,outliers, unique values on IRIS data set.

As seen from the screenshot all the values are clubbed and there is no column name for which those values are calculated.

Current output:

[image: current output]

I need my output to display as

```
                  Mean   Median  Mode   SD    vUnique   Outliers 
sepal.Length      value   value  value  value  value      value
sepal.width       value   value  value  value  value       value
and so on...
```

Comment: hello, can you show the code which lead to this output. with this we can give suggestion how you fill a dataframe with it.

Comment: Hi, I got a solution to use the  function summary(iris).Actually the code I used is

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: did you try 'apply(iris[-5],2,function(x)mean(x))'. Similarly you can change functions for mode,median etc.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution with dplyr using summarise_all (just add statistical function you would like to use):

```
iris[, 1:4] %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  rbind(iris[, 1:4] %>% summarise_all(sd))%>% t()
```